# What is the maximum length of the profile picture url inside the openid jwt "picture" claim, returned by accounts.google.com

Tags: sql, google-openid

I am trying to save the profile picture URL inside an SQL database, and having trouble determining, how big should the VARCHAR(X) column should be. For now, I've just picked a random "should be big enough number" for X but I would like my database to be more optimal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers#417184

Comment: Part 1: Chrome limits the maximum length to 2 MB. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/url_display_guidelines/url_display_guidelines.md#URL-Length

Comment: Part 2: The picture URL is part of an OAuth Identity Token. These tokens are typically used in an HTTP header. Most implementations have a maximum length for all HTTP headers. Apache is 8 KB, IIS is 16 KB.

Comment: Part 3. Google specifies current size limits for OAuth tokens (2048 bytes total). https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#:~:text=to%20service%20accounts.-,Token%20size,Refresh%20tokens%3A%20512%20bytes

Comment: Part 4: IBM specifies the maximum size of an OAuth JWT key or value at 256 bytes. https://www.ibm.com/blogs/security-identity-access/oauth-custom-token-attributes/

Comment: Summary: based upon my experience of never seeing an OAuth token value longer than 256 bytes, I recommend using 256 bytes. If you need to handle anything practical today, use 2048 bytes.

Comment: My picture url right now is 1030 chars (which is too large for our current db field). My other google account picture url is 90 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not say:

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Photo

I notice that internal-company-visibility urls are much longer than public-visibility urls. (eg 1027-1030 chars vs 90-93 chars)

Comment: Related java api link: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/oauth2/model/Userinfoplus.html#getPicture--